# Logstash and iptables

Tags: ubuntu, logstash

I've just installed Logstash on my Ubuntu Server according by [this](http://rdstash.blogspot.ru/2013/01/installing-logstash-as-syslog-server-on.html) tutorial
I've iptables with allowed 80 and 22 ports only. So when Logstash is started I get the following iptables error in the logs.

[image]

What is 224.2.2.4 address and what's should I need to prevent this error?

Comment: looks like you need to allow connections from and to port 54328 UDP

Comment: can you point me to the correct iptables rule?

Comment: one question? have you configured Logstash? the ip and port are default for elasticsearch (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/discovery/zen/)

Comment: my ES resides on another server

Comment: All I do for Logstash is complete Logstash section here: http://rdstash.blogspot.ru/2013/01/installing-logstash-as-syslog-server-on.html

Answer (score 1):

you should check you iptables rules (mostly filter table) to see if there is any rule that prevents the transfer:
thigs u should probably check:

- source IP
- destination IP
- packet type (TCP/UDP)
- network interface
  further more you may check the source-ip  and the destination-ip as well

Comment: Why there is destination port is 224.2.2.4 ?
It's foreign one?

Comment: @Erik: yes it is a foreign address
and its not a port, the 224.2.2.4 is an IP and the `54328` is the port assigned to that IP

Answer (score 0):

224.x.x.x are multicast adresses. Multicast is used when one system wants to communicate to a group of systems. Membership of the groups is managed with IGMP.

ElasticSearch uses multicast to communicate within clusters. Logstash by default connects to ElasticSearch as a cluster node. 
You can fix this by allowing the multicast traffic on your iptables configuration, you will probably need to allow IGMP traffic as well.
Other option is to disable multicast in Logstash and ElasticSearch. You can do this by configuring logstash to use elasticsearch_http output instead of elasticsearch and disable multicast discovery set: discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml